# Compare variable in preceding-sibling with current node

Tags: xslt

I have the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="footnote">
    <xsl:variable name = "string">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name = "bool">
        <xsl:if test="$string = preceding-sibling::node()/$string">
            <xsl:text>false</xsl:test>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="$bool != 'false'">
        <!-- DO STUFF -->
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm trying to check the $string variable of the current node and check it against all previous footnote nodes to see if they have the same $string variable. If it doesn't match up with any of the preceding siblings then it should do stuff, otherwise it should do nothing.

With the code I have, the test "$string = preceding-sibling::node()/$string" always evaluates to true, even when no footnote nodes have been created yet.

Can anyone help me out? I'm having a hard time creating the expression to compare against the variable in all of the previous siblings.

**EDIT:** Sample XML:

```
<xml>
<footnote>Footnote 1</footnote>
<footnote>Footnote 2</footnote>
<footnote>Footnote 1</footnote>
<footnote>Footnote 1</footnote>
<footnore>Footnote 3</footenote>
</xml>
```

I'm trying to transform that into:

```
<xml>
<footnote>Footnote 1</footnote>
<footnote>Footnote 2</footnote>
<footnote>Footnore 3</footnore>
</xml
```

Comment: can you add into queestion xml wich will be aplied this xslt?

Comment: You don't need to define a variable in this case! Please check my answer only template override would take care of getting rid of duplicate nodes(values)..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well. posting Your output XML made it more clear! there you go with solution:

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <footnote>Matching</footnote>
  <footnote>Example1</footnote>
  <footnote>Matching</footnote>
  <footnote>Example2</footnote>
  <footnote>Example3</footnote>
</root>
```

And XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="footnote[.=preceding-sibling::footnote/.]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
  <footnote>Matching</footnote>
  <footnote>Example1</footnote>
  <footnote>Example2</footnote>
  <footnote>Example3</footnote>
</xml>
```

Comment: Tried that and it always evaluates to false.

Comment: Please try now! there was slight misunderstanding .. Now It meets ur requirement

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to check the value of the current footnote `text()` against previous footnote `text()'s` for uniqueness, then you can just check the `preceding-sibling::node()'s text()`:

```
<xsl:if test="$string = preceding-sibling::node()/text()">
```

e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0"
                >
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/xml">
        <xml>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="footnote" />
        </xml>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="footnote">
        <xsl:variable name = "string">
            <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name = "bool">
            <xsl:if test="$string = preceding-sibling::node()/text()">
                <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="$bool != 'false'">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Will turn the input:

```
<xml>
    <footnote>
        someVal
    </footnote>
    <footnote>
        anotherVal
    </footnote>
    <footnote>
        anotherVal
    </footnote>
    <footnote>
        newVal
    </footnote>
</xml>
```

Into:

```
<xml>
  <footnote>
        someVal
    </footnote>
  <footnote>
        anotherVal
    </footnote>
  <footnote>
        newVal
    </footnote>
</xml>
```

You should also look at Muenchian grouping if your intention is to identify groups within elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
<xsl:template match="footnote[not(. = preceding-sibling::footnote)]">
```

to create a template that only fires for the first instance of a given footnote string.  The `. = preceding-sibling::footnote` is true if the string value of this node is the same as that of *any* of its preceding siblings, so `not(....)` will be true if it is different from *all* of them.

But for large documents this will be rather inefficient (quadratic in the number of footnote elements).  Better would be to use `<xsl:for-each-group>` (XSLT 2.0) or Muenchian Grouping (XSLT 1.0) to group the `footnote` elements by their string value and extract the first element from each group.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="fn" match="footnote" use="." />

  <!-- Ignore all but the first footnote for a given value -->
  <xsl:template match="footnote[generate-id() != generate-id(key('fn', .)[1])]" />

  <!-- copy everything else verbatim -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="footnote">

    <xsl:variable name = "string">
      <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name = "bool">
      <xsl:if test="$string != preceding-sibling::node()/text()">
        <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="$bool != 'false'">
        true
    </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="$bool = 'false'">
    false
  </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0 you have a distinct-values function:

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(footnote)">
    <footnote><xsl:value-of select="."/></footnote>
</xsl:for-each>
```